# Postgres/GCS/Python: Insert data stored in variable that read from GCS to postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read a file from GCS and store it in variable and create a postgresql table from it. I can connect to GCs from my code and be able to store data in variabe with this:

```
result = blob.download_as_string()
result = result.decode('utf8').strip()
```

which the printed result are in the correct format. Then, I tried to insert data from this variable into the table which I did:

```
sql = "COPY tablename FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' NULL AS '\\N' CSV HEADER;"
cursor.copy_expert(sql, result)
```

and I got this error:

```
file must be a readable file-like object for COPY FROM; a writable file-like object for COPY TO
```

I also tried with another function:

```
cursor.copy_from(result, 'table' ,sep=',')
```

but I got this result:

```
argument 1 must have a .read() method
```

So, according to my question how can I put the data in the variable to the table I created. Or do I have to download it to my local and use this:

```
sql = "COPY tablename from STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
with open('/path/to/csv' , 'r+') as file:
     cursor.copy_expert(sql, file)
```

This one is worked but I don't want to download it to my local. I just want to read it and insert it into my table

Thank you

Comment: You can use stringIO to provide a "file-like" string to the your function.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? @solarc

Comment: I used `result = StringIO(result)` and it worked! Thank you. You may write in the answer so that I can give a correct to your solution @solarc