# How to read json gzipped file from GCS and write to table?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, google-cloud-storage, gzip

I have a json compress with gzip file (.json.gz) stored in bucket in Google Cloud Storage in which I want to read it and copy it into a postgres table. The json.gz file I have is just a json file with no nested object in it like this:

```
[{
“date”: “2019-03-10T07:00:00.000Z”,
“type”: “chair”,
“total”: 250.0,
"payment": "cash"
},{
“date”: “2019-03-10T07:00:00.000Z”,
“type”: “shirt”,
“total”: 100.0,
"payment": "credit card"
},{
.
.
}]
```

Previously I did similar job like this with csv file in which I can use `download_as_string` function and stored it in variable and use `StringIO` to convert that variable to file-like object and used `copy_expert()` function with the query ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042273/postgres-gcs-python-insert-data-stored-in-variable-that-read-from-gcs-to-postgr)).

So, how can I read a json.gz file in GCS and write it to a table with Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read the data in, I'd go with [gcsfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), Python interface to GCS:

```
import gcsfs
import gzip
import json

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-project')
with fs.open('bucket/path.json.gz') as f:
    gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) 
    file_as_string = gz.read()
    your_json = json.loads(file_as_string)
```

Now that you have your json, you can use the same code as you were using with csv.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By the way, are there any other way that use an official google cloud client libraries like in this [link](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html) instead of gcsfs

Comment: @Jamiewp Sure, this one is though IMO most Pythonic. If your question is resolved please accept the answer and upvote if you feel generous :).

Comment: Currently I am not try it yet but will try it tomorrow

Comment: I tried with your code and `print(g)` outside and it shown only `<gzip GCSFile bucket/testjson.json.gz 0x7f2c8c29b780>`

Comment: I modified with read() and json.loads() and be able to print it out but I got error when trying to insert the data instead lol

Comment: @Jamiewp I have modified the code so that it gives you json. I can help you around insert error, but not in the scope of this question.

Comment: Exactly, I'll find the way on inserting that into the table then